# How to define a document in javascript? WebStorm

Tags: javascript, html, css, webstorm

UPDATE: I fixed the color vs backgroundColor problem. Thanks! However, the code still will not run from WebStorm. Any WebStorm experts out there?

I am learning javascript and trying to manipulate css with js. Here is my code:

```js
document.getElementById("top-left").style.color = "blue";
```

```css
body{
    background-color: black;
}

.container {
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 2.5%;
    padding-left: 30%;
    width: 31em;
}

#title {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    color: green;
    font-size: 4em;
}

#top-left {
    width: 15em;
    height: 15em;
    background: red;
    border-top-left-radius: 100% ;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;


}

#top-right {
    width: 15em;
    height: 15em;
    background: gold;
    border-top-left-radius: 0 ;
    border-top-right-radius: 100%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;




}

#bottom-right {
    width: 15em;
    height: 15em;
    background: orangered;
    border-top-left-radius: 0 ;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;


}

#bottom-left {
    width: 15em;
    height: 15em;
    background: darkgreen;
    border-top-left-radius: 0 ;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="jscode.js"></script>
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id = "title">Title</div>
<div class = "container">
    <div id = "top-left"></div>
    <div id= "top-right"></div>
    <div id = "bottom-left"></div>
    <div id = "bottom-right"></div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

On the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/interestinall/hgo7h5v4/), the script just doesn't do anything. On WebStorm, it throws the following error: ReferenceError: document is not defined.

So my question is: how does one define a document?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As this is about WebStorm, it should be asked as a new question, with adequate title, adequate tagging, and adequate description of the problem in a reproduceable manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, but you're setting `color` instead of `backgroundColor`.

```
document.getElementById("top-left").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

The `color` property is for text that appears in the element.

You don't have to (and can't, anyway) define the `document` object with your own code. It's an object exposed to you by the web browser infrastructure.

Comment: Well I guess you *could* define a `document` in some appropriate environment (Node), but in the browser there's no point.

Comment: Thanks to you and everyone else who picked up by backgroundColor mistake.

Answer (score 2):

> how does one define a document?

Generally speaking. You don't.

JavaScript running in a browser, in a webpage will have a `document` object supplied by the environment.

WebStorm is an IDE with for Node.JS, and you appear to be using the Node.js end of it to get your "document is not defined" result. There are implementations of DOM which would give you such an object there, but your code is clearly trying to run in a webpage, so that isn't a route you should be looking down.

---

Your problem is that you are setting the **foreground** `color`, and you don't have any text to change the colour of. You should be looking at the `backgroundColor` property instead.

Comment: If I understand you right, you are saying that I shouldn't do this in WebStorm because that is not its purpose. Can you recommend another IDE for my purpose? Thanks!

Comment: @interestinall, Webstorm is not inherently limited to server side code. If you have installed its browser extension then it can hijack the browser for debugging a page and any scripts in its context. You need to debug in terms of the document (html) that loads the script, as it makes no sense to separately run a script that refers to DOM/BOM/etc.